# Can I use the attach/detach database option to shut down Azure sql database until i need it

Tags: database-recommendation, azure

I need to use Azure SQL Database once a week for a BI solution.  O load the data in on Monday, perform ETL, and then load the data into a PowerBI model.  After that I don't need the database anymore until next week.  In order to save costs can I just detach the database and attach next week?

Answer (score 1):

No. Attach/detach are not supported on Azure SQL DB. A few workarounds today:

- Change the pricing tier (performance level) to the lowest that can support your database (each tier has a certain size limit), you can bring it up to the require performance level when you need to use it
- Export to Azure blob (very low cost storage) when not needed, import when needed later (ok for smaller databases). More information on this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export
- Delete the database when not needed, restore later. Not recommended but you'll see this suggestion come up quite a bit. Be careful not to delete the server (costs you nothing if you don't have DBs in it) and depending on the pricing tier of the database, backup retention varies from 7 to 35 days. If it's past the period, you're pretty much out of luck. See difference between export/import and backup/restore here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-built-in-backups-vs-importexport-2/